# ASP.NET MVC : controller does not redirect to another page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server that has a local controller for authentication on the same project. I want to sign-in users through this controller and then redirect to homepage or previous page.

However, the `Redirect("~/")` function on the local controller does not seem to work. I tried with different urls including external urls but no success. I tried to solve it many times but was not able. Any help will be appreciated.

Login submit:

```cs
result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Account/Login", loginParameters);
```

Controller:

```cs
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginParameters loginParameters)
    {
        string userName = loginParameters.UserName;
        string password = loginParameters.Password;
        string redirectUrl = loginParameters.RedirectUrl;
            
        if (env.EnvironmentName == "Development" && userName == "admin" && password == "admin")
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin"),
                new(ClaimTypes.Email, "admin")
            };
            roleManager.Roles.ToList().ForEach(r => claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r.Name)));
            await signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(new ApplicationUser { UserName = userName, Email = userName }, false, claims);

            //return Redirect("https://localhost:5001/");
            //return Redirect("https://www.google.com/");
            return Redirect($"~/{redirectUrl}");
        }

        // More stuff
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped(serviceProvider =>
{
    var uriHelper = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
    return new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri) };
});
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

//...
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
    app.Use((ctx, next) =>
    {
        ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
    });
}
else
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default","{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});

app.Run();
```

Problem:

[image: Animation cannot redirect from controller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to using `Radzen` login component because I wanted to switch to `MudBlazor` but it seems calling the `PostAsJsonAsync` on a local controller doesn't redirect to homepage or any page.

By redirecting using the `NavigationManager` on front-end after returning post result does not solve the issue it does not somehow get the signing state of the user.

Therefore, went back to my original code which worked but will prefer if anyone has another solution instead.

Login:

```razor
<RadzenContent Container="main">
  <ChildContent>
    <RadzenHeading Size="H1" Text="Login">
    </RadzenHeading>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <RadzenTemplateForm Action="account/login" Data="@("login")" Method="post">
          <ChildContent>
            <RadzenLogin Register="@LoginRegister" ResetPassword="@LoginResetPassword">
            </RadzenLogin>
          </ChildContent>
        </RadzenTemplateForm>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ChildContent>
</RadzenContent>
```

Controller:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName, string password, string redirectUrl)
{
    if (env.EnvironmentName == "Development" && userName == "admin" && password == "admin")
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "admin")
        };

        roleManager.Roles.ToList().ForEach(r => claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r.Name)));
        await signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(new ApplicationUser { UserName = userName, Email = userName }, isPersistent: false, claims);

        return Redirect($"~/{redirectUrl}");
    }
    
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In what context are you calling your `Account/Login` endpoint from the client?
I'm not certain this is the case, but I imagine Blazor prevents automatic redirects as to not lose navigation state, as Blazor navigation is not handled in the conventional way (the entire site is essentially one page).

You could simply make your request to `Account/Login`, grab the `Location` header from the result, and then explicilty navigate to that URI using the injected `NavigationManager`. This, however, begs the question whether your backend API should be responsible for determining where to send the user (in this case some home-page). Since the user never leaves the Blazor app, something like this should suffice:

```cs
@inject NavigationManager UriHelper
...
loginResult = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Account/Login", loginParameters);
if (loginResult.IsSuccessStatusCode) // API should return 200 OK on login success
    UriHelper.NavigateTo("home");
else
  // Do something else
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I tried it before but I can't get the authentication status, so when it goes back to home page the admin is not signed in.